# VBA code. How to loop through a column, find values in between 0.9 and 1 and then offset 4 rows to the left of them for those values?

Tags: excel, vba

```
Set ColumnE = Worksheets("Phonebook").Range("E:E")
Dim Names As Long
'In this we will write the names of the people who have upcoming birthdays.
For Each rng In ColumnE
    If (rng.Value >= 0.9 And rng.Value <= 1) Then

    End If
Next
MsgBox " " & Names & " has an upcoming birthday."
```

Now, I need your help to finish this because I have no idea what I'm doing anymore.

Basically, what I have is a column in excel that calculates the time until a persons birthday based on their birthday; in percentages. Basically it says John was born yadda yadda, 90% until his birthday.

I find the values in between 0.9 and 1, which is between 90% and 100% and now comes the tricky part.

I need your help on how to find the names for those people who have their birthday coming up soon. The names are 4 rows to the left of the percentage, or 5 if you include the column with the percentages.

**I want this loop to find everyone whose birthday is coming up, and enter their names into the msgbox so when I click the button, it tells me which people are having their birthday soon.**

As far as I know, I'm supposed to use the .Offset thingy somehow, but I have no idea how to do that and then enter multiple names into the msgbox as one dim.

I would really appreciate your help my dudes!

Comment: `Dim theNames as String....theNames = theNames & IIf(len(theNames )>0,vbLf,"") & rng.offset(0,-4).Value`

Comment: @TimWilliams Yes! That worked perfectly and exactly as I needed it to! Thank you so much! I love you!

Answer (score 0):

Use `Offset` to navigate around a cell

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Phonebook")
Dim LRow As Long, MyCell As Range, Names As String
LRow = ws.Range("E" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For Each MyCell In ws.Range("E2:E" & LRow)
    If MyCell >= 0.9 And MyCell <= 1 Then
        Names = MyCell.Offset(, -4) & ", " & Names
    End If
Next MyCell

Names = Left(Names, Len(Names) - 2)

If Len(Names) Then
    MsgBox Names & " has an upcoming birthday!"
Else
    MsgBox "No upcoming birthdays."
End If

End Sub
```